# Django filtering on Window functions

Tags: django, django-models, window-functions

I have two Models in Django, `A` and `B`.

Each `A` has several `B`s assigned to it, and the `B`s are ordered, which is done with a field `B.order_index` that counts upwards from zero for any `A`.

I want to write a query that checks if there is any `A` where some of the `B`s have a gap or have duplicate `order_index` values.

In SQL, this could be done like this:

```
SELECT order_index, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a_id ORDER BY order_index ASC) - 1 AS rnk
WHERE rnk = order_index'
```

However, when I try this in Django with this code:

```
B.objects.annotate(rank=RawSQL("RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a_id ORDER BY order_index ASC) - 1", [])).filter(rank=F('order_index'))
```

I get an error saying:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: window functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ...- 1) AS "rank" FROM "main_b" WHERE (RANK() OVE...
```

In SQL this would be easy enough to fix by wrapping the entire thing in a subquery and applying the Where clause to that subquery. How can I do the same in Django?

Comment: Django 2.0 introduced Window functions into the ORM:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Comment: Hi @Florian Dietz. Did you find the ORM solution for this problem?

Comment: There is a ticket in django bug tracker: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333

Answer (score 4):

One possible work-around to express such a query would be to use https://github.com/dimagi/django-cte.

```
from django_cte import With

cte = With(
    B.objects.all().annotate(
        rank=Window(
            expression=Rank(),
            partition_by=F('a_id'),
            order_by=F('order_index').asc()
        )
    )
)

cte.join(B.objects.all(), id=cte.col.id).with_cte(cte).annotate(
    rank=cte.col.rank
).filter(
    rank=F('order_index')
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tested this but using the new Window functions mentioned in the comment by @Bobort you could try something like this, the SQL it produces is pretty close to what you want apart from the "-1"

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models.functions import Rank

B.objects.annotate(rank=Window(
    expression=Rank(),
    order_by=F('order_index').desc(),
    partition_by=[F('a_id')]))
```

Comment: The question is asking how to filter on `rank`.