# How do I get the first page of results for multiple things in one query

Tags: django, postgresql

The problem is a little hard to explain, but I'll do my best.  I'm constructing a GraphQL server in Django (using Graphene), and part of this is the need to batch up database queries to avoid n+1 problems. Which means, when say fetching a set of Events, rather than making one query per Event ID, we make a single query with `where id in (...)`.

I'm trying to achieve the same with lists. My immediate use case is that every Event has a Venue, and I want to retrieve the next 5 (this is arbitrary) events for each Venue, in just one query.

(Note: for a full justification behind this, [I wrote an article a while ago](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/optimizing-your-graphql-request-waterfalls-7c3f3360b051))

The PostgreSQL query I've come up with is this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (PARTITION BY
                venue_id
            ORDER BY
                starts_at,
                ends_at,
                id) AS row_index
        FROM
            events_event
        WHERE
            starts_at >= '2018-05-20') x
    WHERE
        row_index <= 5
```

I don't *think* I'll have the need for case statements, because I don't think there's a realistic need to be able to batch up subsequent pages -- just the initial ones.

So I have a few questions about this:

1. Is there a better way of writing this query?
2. Is this preferable to firing off multiple (realistically between 10 and 30) queries in parallel to do this the conventional way?
3. How can I achieve this query using the Django ORM (without dropping down to raw SQL)?

The third question is the one I'm banging my head over because the ORM seems to provide all the necessary building blocks (I'm using Django 2.0), but I can't figure out how to stick them all together.

This is what I have so far using Django:

```
Event.objects.annotate(
    row_number=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(), 
        partition_by=[F('venue_id')], 
        order_by=[F('starts_at').asc(), F('ends_at').asc(), F('id').asc()]
    )
)
```

But I've been unable to find a way to filter on row_number, because I don't want to return everything -- just the first 5. When I try the following, Django tells me that filtering isn't allowed on Window clauses:

```
Event.objects.annotate(
    row_number=Window(
        expression=RowNumber(), 
        partition_by=[F('venue_id')], 
        order_by=[F('starts_at').asc(), F('ends_at').asc(), F('id').asc()]
    )
).filter(row_number__lte=5)
```

Comment: I think this answer can help you with ORM approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191865/7897796

Comment: @T.Tokic I got more-or-less as far as this. The problem is that I can't filter on the value. Let me update the question.

Comment: Looks like it may not yet be possible via the ORM: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333

Comment: It looks like the restriction on DB level and here we have the workaround solution: https://www.sqltheater.com/2017/09/28/cant-use-row_number-where/ (putting the WHERE clause in the outer query and the window function in the subquery) but I have no idea how it achieve it with ORM.

Here we have the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245123/django-filtering-on-window-functions#comment88119312_46245123

Comment: Yeah, I found all the same things. I'm wondering if there's a hacky way I can modify the SQL just prior to execution to add the outer query. The outer query doesn't impact the shape of the data, so it's conceivable that it'd work.