# Django queryset top 3 of sum for each year

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need to find the top 3 customers per year from the sum of their related invoices. So, I got 2 models `Customer` related to `Invoice` by a FK.

Edited:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Invoice(models.Model):
    created = AutoCreatedField(_('created'))
    total = DecimalField()
    company = models.ForeignKey('users.Company', verbose_name=_('Company'),
                            on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='invoices',
                            null=True)
```

I get the total sales foreach as following:

```
qs = Company.objects\
        .annotate(year=TruncYear('invoices__created')).values('year', 'name')\
        .annotate(total=Sum('invoices__total'))\
        .order_by('year', 'total')
```

But what if I'd like to get only the top 3 per year? Should I iterate manually:

```
years = [year.year for year in set(qs.values_list('year', flat=True))]

for y in years:
     new_qs = qs.filter(year__year=y).order_by('-total')[:3]
     my_top.append(new_qs)
```

Isn't it a way to get the limited queryset in one shot?

Comment: How do your models look like? Add relevant models to the OP

Comment: Thanks for the interest but here, It won't add any relevant info. You have A related to B, by a FK, that's it.

Comment: Are you using a DB with [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) function?

Comment: @Marco Yes, Recent PG: It's interesting. it'd need raw sql.

Comment: Your request is hard to implement in raw sql. And you want to do it in ORM? You can use raw sql in Django for such cases (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: Indeed, no way to have it easily in ORM. I ended up with some python computation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on several answers, there is no other way than your suggested approach. See [Clean way to use postgresql window functions in django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781669/clean-way-to-use-postgresql-window-functions-in-django-orm) or [Django filtering on Window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245123/django-filtering-on-window-functions).

Nevertheless, I would still like to share the windowing function to add a rank on each row. You can do whatever you want with it during iteration:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncYear, Rank
from django.db.models import F, Window, Q, Sum

Company.objects\
    .annotate(year=TruncYear('invoices__created')).values('year', 'name')\
    .annotate(total=Sum('invoices__total'))\
    .annotate(
        rank=Window(
            expression=Rank(),
            order_by=Sum('invoices__total'),
            partition_by=[F('year')]
        )
    )
```

This will result in:

```
{'name': 'Company A', 'year': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'total': Decimal('3000.00'), 'rank': 1}
{'name': 'Company B', 'year': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'total': Decimal('6000.00'), 'rank': 2}
{'name': 'Company C', 'year': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'total': Decimal('9000.00'), 'rank': 3}
{'name': 'Company D', 'year': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'total': Decimal('12000.00'), 'rank': 4}
{'name': 'Company A', 'year': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'total': Decimal('2000.00'), 'rank': 1}
{'name': 'Company B', 'year': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'total': Decimal('4000.00'), 'rank': 2}
...
```